# how to write function with php (similar to mysql_query)

Tags: php, c, function

how we can see the contents such as mysql_query() functions ?

How to write similar function with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the source of the PHP function, you would have to [download the source](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) and look at the files and folders in the "ext" folder. PHP is written in C. You could write your own extensions in C and compile them in to PHP.

You can write your own **PHP function**, in PHP, like this:

```
function name_of_your_function($parameter1, $parameter2)
{
  // Do something useful here.
}
```

For more information, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php.

Comment: How to write similar to mysql_query() function with php?

Comment: @MalcolmX - Again, there are 2 options... In C as an extension, which I doubt is what you want to do, or with PHP as in my short example. See the "User-defined" functions section of the link I provided above.